# Resharper command line tool throwing exceptions

Tags: resharper

I discovered resharper command line tools. I am using the command utility dupfinder.exe to check duplicates in my code. I am using windows 10 64 bit. I executed the command:

```
dupfinder sample.sln -o=output.xml
```

where sample.sln is the file I am evaluating and output.xml where dupfinder will write the results. I am getting the following output:

```
JetBrains Duplicates Finder 2019.3.1
Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.42000 under Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0
Could not bind the component argument descriptor on JetBrains.ProjectModel.BuildTools.BuildToolPlatformsProviderBase+SolutionWatcher. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

--- EXCEPTION #1/4 [NullReferenceException]
Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException
ClassName = System.NullReferenceException
Data.ThreadLocalDebugInfo = Run
HResult = E_POINTER=COR_E_NULLREFERENCE=80004003
Source = JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.CommandLine.Common
StackTraceString = "
  at JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.CommandLine.Common.Console.BatchTool.MsBuild.CommandLineSolutionToolset.CommandLineToolsProvider.Discover(BuildToolEnvironment env)
 at JetBrains.ProjectModel.BuildTools.BuildToolContainer.Discover(IReadOnlyCollection`1 providers, BuildToolEnvironment env)
 at JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.CommandLine.Common.Console.BatchTool.MsBuild.CommandLineSolutionToolset..ctor(Lifetime lifetime, ILogger logger, ICommandLineToolSettings settings, BuildToolContainer buildToolContainer)
"

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/4 [TargetInvocationException]
Message = "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException
ClassName = System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Data.ThreadLocalDebugInfo = Run
InnerException = "Exception #1 at Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_TARGETINVOCATION=80131604
Source = mscorlib
StackTraceString = "
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartCatalogTypeComponentDescriptor.CreateInstanceOf(Type type, IValueResolveContext context)
 at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartCatalogTypeComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.SignatureResolution.BindArguments(List`1 argumentDescriptors, Object origin)
"

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #3/4 [InvalidOperationException]
Message = "Could not bind the component argument descriptor on JetBrains.ProjectModel.BuildTools.BuildToolPlatformsProviderBase+SolutionWatcher."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException
Data.ArgumentIndex = 1
Data.Origin = JetBrains.ProjectModel.BuildTools.BuildToolPlatformsProviderBase+SolutionWatcher
InnerException = "Exception #2 at Root.InnerException.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #4/4 [LoggerException]
Message = "Could not bind the component argument descriptor on JetBrains.ProjectModel.BuildTools.BuildToolPlatformsProviderBase+SolutionWatcher."
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = "Exception #3 at Root.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = "
  at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Error(ILogger this, Exception exception, ExceptionOrigin origin, String comment)
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.SignatureResolution.BindArguments(List`1 argumentDescriptors, Object origin)
 at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartCatalogTypeComponentDescriptor.CreateInstanceOf(Type type, IValueResolveContext context)
 at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartCatalogTypeComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.InitializationStrategyDefault.Schedule(Lifetime lifetime, ICollection`1 dscs, IComponentContainer container)
 at JetBrains.Application.Components.ComponentStorage.ComposeDescriptors(ICollection`1 descriptors)
 at JetBrains.ProjectModel.SolutionInstance.OpenSolutionInstance(ISolutionLoadTasksScheduler taskScheduler)
 at JetBrains.ProjectModel.SolutionManagerBase.CreateSolutionInstance(SolutionElement solutionElement, SolutionInstance solutionInstance)
 at JetBrains.ProjectModel.Impl.SolutionManagerImpl.CreateSolution(SolutionLocation solutionLocation)
 at JetBrains.CommandLine.DupFinder.Application.Console.DupFinderProductMain.RunGuarded()
 at JetBrains.CommandLine.DupFinder.Application.Console.DupFinderProductMain.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Run>b__0()
 at JetBrains.Threading.ReentrancyGuard.Execute(String name, Action action)
 at JetBrains.CommandLine.DupFinder.Application.Console.DupFinderProductMain.Run()
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at JetBrains.Application.Environment.RunsPublicStaticIntMain.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
 at JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
 at JetBrains.Threading.JetDispatcher.Closure.Execute()
 at JetBrains.Util.Concurrency.WinJetDispatcher.ProcessQueue(Int32 nMinBucket)
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeDelegateCore()
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
 at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
 at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
 at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
 at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
 at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
 at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
 at JetBrains.Application.Environment.IJetHostEx.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RunHostMessageLoop>b__0(Lifetime lifetime)
 at JetBrains.Lifetimes.Lifetime.Using(Action`1 action)
 at JetBrains.Application.Environment.IJetHostEx.RunHostMessageLoop(IComponentContainer containerEnv)
 at JetBrains.Application.Environment.HostParameters.JetHostParametersCaller.RunMainLoop(ComponentContainer containerEnv)
 at JetBrains.Application.Environment.JetEnvironment.InternalRun(JetHostParametersCaller host, ComponentContainer containerEnv)
 at JetBrains.Application.Environment.JetEnvironment.CreateAndRun(Full hostparams)
 at JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.CommandLine.Common.Application.CommandLineProgram.Main(Assembly assembly, Type environmentZoneType, HostInfo hostInfo, ICommandLineProductInfo productInfo, String[] args, IJetHostMixin[] mixins)
 at JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.CommandLine.Common.Application.CommandLineProgram.Run[TZone,TProductInfo](String productHostShortName, String[] args)
 at JetBrains.CommandLine.DupFinder.Application.DupFinderProgram.Main(String[] args)
"

Component JetBrains.ProjectModel.BuildTools.BuildToolPlatformsProviderBase+SolutionWatcher [Singleton, Corrupted] construction has failed. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
// more stacktrace omitted due to number of character limitations
```

I do not understand the errors. What should I do?

Comment: The new version has been released, so please try again https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=resharper-sdk

Comment: @Alexander Kurakin yes. Working now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report about the same exception [on JetBrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-477560). It is going to be fixed in the next bugfix update soon.

UPDATE: Fixed in [2019.3.2 build](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=resharper-sdk)